# How to convert an XMl document into String in blackberry JDE 4.7

Tags: blackberry

Can anyone help me with code for converting an xml document into string in blackberry JDE 4.7 
I wanted the complete xml document into a single String.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with *DataInputStream#readUTF()* rather easily.  Or if you want a little more control you could use *DataInputStream.readChar()*, put the returned chars in a StringBuffer and then convert the StringBuffer into a String once reading is complete.  A short uncompiled code example follows:

```
try {
    Connection con = Connector.open(path);
    if(con instanceof FileConnection) {
        DataInputStream dis = ((FileConnection)con).openDataInputStream();
        String strFile = dis.readUTF();
    }
} catch(...) {
    ...
} finally {
    ...
}
```